# Sending simultaneous JSON requests via Python 3.5

Tags: python, json, csv, parallel-processing, python-3.5

So I have this and it's working:

```
import requests
import csv


my_list = [item1, item2, item3, item4]


def write_results(file, list_to_iterate):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        fields = ("column_item", "column_value")
        wr = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter=",", fieldnames=fields, lineterminator='\n')
        wr.writeheader()
        for each_item in list_to_iterate:
            try:
                r = requests.get('https://www.somewebsite.com/api/something?this='+each_item).json()
                value = str(r['value'])
            except:
                value = "none"
            wr.writerow({'column_item': each_item, 'column_value': value})


write_results('spreadsheet.csv', my_list)
```

I'm basically writing the outputs that I fetch from a JSON output page to a CSV. My function works great and operates exactly as intended. The only drawback is that I'm actually iterating through a huge list, so I'm having to send a ton of requests. I'm wondering if it is possible for me to send my requests in parallel rather than waiting for a response then sending the next one. The order in which I write to the CSV doesn't even matter, so it's not a problem if I retrieve responses out of sync with my list.

I've tried and looked at all these different methods, but I just cannot get my head around a solid solution. All the examples I've seen are more geared towards web scraping and they are using a total different set of modules (not using requests).

Any help is gladly appreciated. This is driving me nuts. Also, if it's possible, I'd like to use as many native modules as possible.

Note: Python 3.5

Comment: Untested but this example should work: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example (replaces `PRIMES` with your list and `is_prime` with a function that does the work for one element).

Comment: Thank you Simeon. I haven't tried using the concurrent.futures module yet, I will give this a shot tonight.